# Which kickstand to choose?

Tags: kickstand

I need to replace my kickstand because it broke, so I need tips like is there any strategy on how to choose and install that part? Do they all fit into that hole where they need to be attached, or are there different sizes of stand for different bikes?

Comment: I assume you mean "kickstand" and not "repair stand".

Comment: Do you mean a kick stand that fits to the bike? Most kick stands designed to fit in the same place on the bike well be reasonably interchangeable, but not all. Some need cutting down on some bikes, but one of mine is adjustable for the height of the bracket. At first your question read like it was about a stand that you put the bike on to work on it, so you may want to clarify, perhaps with a picture.

Comment: Do you even need one?

Answer (score 3):

[Pletscher](http://www.rivbike.com/category-s/335.htm) and [Greenfield](http://www.greenfieldny.com/chart_bicycle.htm) both make decent kickstands. The most common kickstand is a single leg model that attaches just behind the bottom bracket. Pletscher also makes a [double leg kickstand](http://www.rivbike.com/product-p/k21.htm) that mounts in the same place and Greenfield makes a kickstand they call the [Stabilizer](http://www.greenfieldny.com/chart_bicycle.htm#stabilizer) that attaches near the rear dropout on the non-drive side.

The double leg kickstand is nice if you need the bike to be stable while you load cargo or if you use a single-wheel trailer like the B.o.B Yak or Ibex. On the other hand it is a, small, bit more trouble to use since you have to lift the bike a bit to all the legs to fold down.

Most kickstands seem to come in a size that is too long. The leg(s) need to be cut to a length that is appropriate for your bike. It's easy as long as you have a hacksaw – on the Pletscher you just measure from the ground to the center of the bottom bracket and then find that dimension on the where it is marked on the kickstand and cut it off.

Depending on where you park the bike you might want to get a [foot](http://www.rivbike.com/product-p/k3.htm) for the kickstand either to protect a floor or to provide some resistance to sinking into soft surfaces.

Comment: Good points - there's also the tourer style of prop which goes from the saddle clamp down to the ground, and is not attached to the bike.

Comment: Yes, I've cut down generic kickstands several times, using a plain hacksaw.  It's a simple process if you have any mechanical inclination at all.  About the only way to screw it up is to cut it too short, and, if you don't have the old one to compare to, you can cut it long to start and trim down a bit at a time.

Comment: If you cut your kickstand a little too short, say half an inch or a centimeter than putting a foot on it will probably fix the problem.

Comment: The double kickstands can be left a little long. How often is the ground flat enough for 4 points of contact anyway? And you'd need to get both legs exactly the same length. With the legs and one wheel on the ground minor tweaks on the other wheel are easy (brakes, gears, pumping with a floor pump) even at the side of the road. My reason for choosing the double is loading a toddler. You can't step away from the bike but you can use both hands to do up their straps.