# How to mount a kickstand on a bike with no kickstand mounts?

Tags: frames, kickstand

I have several bikes. Unfortunately, many of them lack the all-important
kickstand mount which makes the bikes practically unusable for everyday tasks
unless there's some possibility of mounting a kickstand on a frame that has no
kickstand mounts.

I don't understand why such poor frame designs lacking kickstand mounts are so
prevalent. How can I mount a kickstand on such frames?

Comment: I disagree with the premise that kickstands are essential, and that lacking an integrated kickstand mount makes for poor frame design.

Comment: Kickstand - device that holds your bike upright just long enough for you to be too far away to stop it from falling over.  If it's important for your bike to remain upright, use something with a higher probability of working.

Comment: The kickstand was the first thing I removed when I got a bike at 15. I think it stayed on for less than a month No other bike  I owned had one thereafter. Next item were the mudguards, the dynamo and the lights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I install the kickstand?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/29342/where-should-i-install-the-kickstand)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which kickstand to choose?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34973/which-kickstand-to-choose)

Comment: Voted to close because there are a bunch of similar threads and the wording of the question is silly. A kickstand on a racing bike, or a downhill mountain bike, or any number of other bicycles is fundamentally stupid.

Comment: Having recently added kickstands (yes two) on my Flevo recumbent (20" wheels and a design different from anything like the norm) I do not agree with them not being needed. Since I have them I have used them almost every day, even when there is a wall to park against, there is less damage to the bike if it is on its stands.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to mount a kickstand on a frame lacking mounts:

**Many aluminum frames:**

Aluminum bikes tend to have oval chainstays: in the vertical direction, the
chainstay has a larger dimension than in the horizontal direction. This allows
a kickstand mounting design where the kickstand mount consists of two curved
plates that attach at both sides of the left chainstay. Between the curved
plates and the chainstay, there are usually provided several plastic or rubber
cushions that are of slightly different dimensions. The cushions adapt the
surface of the plates (that may not match the curvature of the chaistay) to the
surface of the chainstay. The reason this design works is that if you clamp an
oval object around an oval tube, you can't rotate the oval object because the
oval shape keeps it in position. However, the bolts usually need to be
tightened really tight, causing the clamping forces to be large, so there's a
risk of deforming the chainstay if it's very lightweight and thus fragile.

The benefit of this mount design is that it works even with disc brakes, but
the drawback is that it requires an oval chainstay (more common on aluminum
frames) and can deform the chainstay.

**Frames with no disc brakes:**

On frames with no disc brakes, arguably the best way to attach a kickstand is
to select a model that clamps both around the left chainstay and around the
left seatstay. Usually they are adjustable for different distances between the
chainstay and seatstay.

The benefit is that the clamping force needed is not very great as the leverage
given by the two-tube mounting design is large enough to keep the bicycle
upright. Thus, there is little risk of deforming the tubes even if the tubes
are very lightweight and thus at risk of deforming if the kickstand clamps only
around the chainstay and not around the seatstay too.

However, disc brakes usually prevent this mounting design from working because
the kickstand attaches on the very location that is needed by the disc
brake caliper.

**Frames with long chainstays:**

There are kickstands that mount between the bottom bracket and the rear tire,
clamping two plates on top of the chainstays and on bottom of the chainstays.
This can be an approach to mount kickstand on a long chainstay bike, but won't
work if the chainstays are short. However, this mounting mechanism suffers from
a number of drawbacks:

- The kickstand can interfere with cranks, especially if the cranks have a
  narrow Q factor
- This works only with long chainstays, so on "modern" bikes where the
  chainstays are unfortunately very short, this won't work
- If there are fenders, they can complicate mounting unless the fender is
  mounted on a chainstay bridge (more common on long chainstay bikes than on
  short chainstay bikes).

Answer (score 5):

Kickstands historically mount to the underside of both chainstays, just aft of the bottom bracket.  Many bike frames incorporate a stiffener plate here, with a large bolthole for a stand.  You do not need this stiffener plate for a stand. Example:

[image: By The original uploader was AndrewDressel at English Wikipedia. - Transferred from en.wikipedia to Commons by Nillerdk., CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=3820674]

This stand clearly clamps an upper and lower plate around the chainstays and you can see the stiffener aft of that, as a tube on this frame.

---

However there are many other options:

Not quite a kickstand, but there are items intended for tourers where the traditional kickstand might be unreachable or obscured.  Its essentially a long stick, often collapsible, that props between the ground and your saddle, or some other high point on your bike.

A tourer is weight-conscious, so these can substitute for a tent pole to get double duty out of the weight.  You could use any lightweight stick wedged under the saddle too, doesn't need to be fancy.

[image] [image: https://www.pathlesspedaled.com/2010/06/01/review-click-stand-folding-bike-stand/]
 A "Click-stand"

---

There are stands designed to work off the front wheel, but they still require a second stand elsewhere.  The front wheel kickstand cannot hold the whole bike.

[image]

---

A third option is to use a rear propstand, instead of a kickstand.  This clamps to the rear axle on both sides, and stands the whole bike up.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Utility_bicycle_kickstand.jpg By Brosen - Polish Wikipedia pl:Grafika:Rowerholender.jpg, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=428409]

These are more common on heavy bikes like cargo bikes or dutch utility bikes, they are relatively heavy, all on the rear axle, and probably will not work with disk brakes.

---

As per your answer, there are clamp-on stands for the left chainstay that may extend up to the seat stay for additional security against rotation.

Some kickstands secure under the left-side rear axle nut and point rearward when stowed.

---

Finally we should consider the null-case of **no-stand**.  The world is full of things on which one may lean a bicycle.  Bike rack/stand, trees, fences, bus stop/shelter,  poles/traffic lights,  etc

You can also lay your bike down gently on almost any surface without causing damage, though they do take up more space this way.

If you're riding with someone else, each bike can lean against the other.  This takes some care but is totally possible.

[image: https://acdevadventures.blog/2020/08/09/lifwide-learning/]

Comment: The  'oval chainstay' type also works on flat rectangular bars, as on my Flevo bike. Solid steel, so less risk on deforming.

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know something about your bike. On low-end steel framed bikes the two most common mountings are using the kickstand plate welded between the chainstays, and, where that is absent, using a kickstand with a clamp which grabs both chainstays. With aluminum frames, or frames with odd geometry you may need a different approach.

[image]